# PHPMyAdmin errors on large/complex queries

Tags: phpmyadmin

We are using PHPMyAdmin 5.2.1 on PHP 8.2.9 and MariaDB 10.6.14

Any time we try and run queries where a lot of data is expected to be returned, we are getting errors in PHPMyAdmin - sometimes the screen just refreshes and no data gets returned at all and others we get errors like below (this happened when trying to sort a table with 5M rows by created date - both via UI and also by manually typing out the query). There is nothing in the error_log.

This works fine for queries if we are very specific and only return 10 rows for example.

php.ini "relevant" settings are:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 20000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
```

Ideally we want to try and avoid downgrading but has anyone come across this? Is there anything we can change settings wise which might be limiting query size etc?

[image]